# How do I reinstall the db.sqlite3 file in django

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner with django and I accidentally deleted the db.sqlite3 file in my django project.
I made a new django project but the db.sqlite3 file was not in it. I also uninstalled and reinstalled django and project but the db.sqlite3 file still wasn't there in the project. What do I do.
Thank you.

Comment: Run the migrations again, and a new one will appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am a beginner with django and I accidentally deleted the db.sqlite3 file in my django project. I made a new django project but the db.sqlite3 file was not in it. I also uninstalled and reinstalled django and project but the db.sqlite3 file still wasn't there in the project. What do I do. Thank you.

1. Delete everything except **init**.py file from migration folder in all django apps
2. Make changes in your models (models.py).
3. Run the command python manage.py makemigrations or python3 manage.py makemigrations
4. Then run the command python manage.py migrate.